# Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies

Tags: reference, publish, .net-standard

When I debug my MVC app everything is OK, but when I run my published app, I get this error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException
> Message : Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified. StackTrace :    at
> System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule
> pModule, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob,
> Int32* pcNamedArgs)    at
> System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule module,
> IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor, IntPtr& blob, IntPtr blobEnd, Int32&
> namedArgs)    at
> System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule
> decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount,
> RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList
> derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)    at
> System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeMethodInfo
> method, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)    at
> DevExpress.DataAccess.ObjectBinding.ObjectMember..ctor(MemberInfo
> memberInfo)    at
> DevExpress.DataAccess.Native.ObjectBinding.ObjectDataSourceFillHelper.<>c.b__24_5(MemberInfo
> info)    at
> System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()    at
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at DevExpress.DataAccess.Native.Web.ObjectDataSourceWizardService.GetMemberInfo(Type type, IObjectDataSourceMemberFilterService filterMemberService)    at DevExpress.DataAccess.Native.Web.ObjectDataSourceWizardService.GetAvailableObjectDescriptions(String context)    at lambda_method(Closure , IQueryBuilderRequestController , String )    at DevExpress.XtraReports.Web.Native.ClientControls.Services.RequestManagerBase`2.WrapWithTryCatchAction(String
> controllerTypeName, String methodName, String webActionName,
> ControllerFunc invoker, TController controller, String json)

I have MVC app with target framework: .NET Framework 4.5.2. I have seen [this post](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/328), but didn't help me. What could I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 2019 and .Net core then at the time of publishing, it should be giving you a file called [solution-name].deps.json. Replace this file as well when you are publishing it on server. This file contains the address of all the dll files. Find your problematic file here and check if the file does exist at the mentioned location.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I don't use  .Net core. The stranger thing is that the error occurs when opening the published app. It's like a file is not being transferred on publish action.

Comment: There must be a configuration file in your published folder, that will be having a path of mentioned dll, you have to correct that path, that is the basic concept. Please also make sure that in your published folder this dll exists

Comment: I found on .csproj file that I have a line: <Reference Include="netstandard" />. If I replace it with <Reference Include="netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />; I get errors in my code.